# Smarty syntax error: variable in my variable

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I've an issue with Smarty. I've to reference to an array with a specific key. Let me explain. This string contains the **value** I want:

```
{$array1.something[$key].id}
```

Meanwhile this other one contains the **key**:

```
{$array2.something[$key].id}
```

I want to combine both of them in this way:

```
{$array1.something[$array2.something[$key].id].id}
```

Trust me, it works perfectly in PHP but I'm can't manage to translate this logic in Smary since it gives me a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Smarty error - syntax error: unrecognized tag: $array1.something[$array2.something[$key].id].id (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 448) in Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Let me try to make it even more simple with an example.

```
1. {$array2.something[$key].id} returns 18 (the key)
2. {$array1.something[$array2.something[$key].id].id} then would be {$array1.something[18].id} 
3. {$array1.something[18].id} should return 999 (the value) but instead of this it gives me a fatal error
```

As you understand it's just a Syntax error. How should I write this statement?

Comment: it should be `{$array1.something[{$array2.something[$key].id}].id}` or if not  then try like `$key1 = {$array2.something[$key].id};  {$array1.something[$key1].id};`

Answer (score 0):

check `{assign}` http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

make `keyVal` = 18

```
{assign "keyVal" $array1.something[$key].id}
```

then output your desired value

```
{$array1.something[$keyVal].id}
```